# How do I read configuration settings from Symfony2 config.yml?

Tags: symfony, configuration

I have added a setting to my config.yml file as such:

```
app.config:
    contact_email: somebody@gmail.com
    ...
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to read it into a variable. I tried something like this in one of my controllers:

```
$recipient =
$this->container->getParameter('contact_email');
```

But I get an error saying:

> The parameter "contact_email" must be
>   defined.

I've cleared my cache, I also looked everywhere on the Symfony2 reloaded site documentation, but I can't find out how to do this.

Probably just too tired to figure this out now. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Rather than defining `contact_email` within `app.config`, define it in a `parameters` entry:

```
parameters:
    contact_email: somebody@gmail.com
```

You should find the call you are making within your controller now works.

Comment: How would this work with the Dev / Prod environments? So for testing I want the emails to send to a test email and production would get another email

Comment: @Phill: If you are using the standard swiftmailer in your symfony2, you can use the following setting in your config_dev.yml:   `swiftmailer:
    delivery_address:  dev@example.com`  You can find more information  in the [Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/dev_environment.html)

Comment: Should I inject container class everywhere(controller, entity, class)   when I use this statement **$this->container->getParameter('contact_email');**? or is there a simpler way to do so without injecting container class?

Comment: According to this solution how can I access to nested properties ?

Comment: @webblover Just insert the parameter itself using the `%parameter_name%` - notation (in YAML)

Answer (score 174):

While the solution of moving the `contact_email` to `parameters.yml` is easy, as proposed in other answers, that can easily clutter your parameters file if you deal with many bundles or if you deal with nested blocks of configuration.

- First, I'll answer strictly the question.
- Later, I'll give an approach for getting those configs from services without ever passing via a common space as parameters.

**FIRST APPROACH: Separated config block, getting it as a parameter**

With an extension ([more on extensions here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)) you can keep this easily "separated" into different blocks in the `config.yml` and then inject that as a parameter gettable from the controller.

Inside your Extension class inside the `DependencyInjection` directory write this:

```
class MyNiceProjectExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load( array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container )
    {
        // The next 2 lines are pretty common to all Extension templates.
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $processedConfig = $this->processConfiguration( $configuration, $configs );
    
        // This is the KEY TO YOUR ANSWER
        $container->setParameter( 'my_nice_project.contact_email', $processedConfig[ 'contact_email' ] );

        // Other stuff like loading services.yml
    }
```

Then in your config.yml, config_dev.yml and so you can set

```
my_nice_project:
    contact_email: someone@example.com
```

To be able to process that `config.yml` inside your `MyNiceBundleExtension` you'll also need a `Configuration` class in the same namespace:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root( 'my_nice_project' );
        
        $rootNode->children()->scalarNode( 'contact_email' )->end();
        
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the config from your controller, as you desired in your original question, but keeping the `parameters.yml` clean, and setting it in the `config.yml` in separated sections:

```
$recipient = $this->container->getParameter( 'my_nice_project.contact_email' );
```

**SECOND APPROACH: Separated config block, injecting the config into a service**

For readers looking for something similar but for getting the config from a service, there is even a nicer way that never clutters the "paramaters" common space and does even not need the `container` to be passed to the service (passing the whole container is practice to avoid).

This trick above still "injects" into the parameters space your config.

Nevertheless, after loading your definition of the service, you could add a method-call like for example `setConfig()` that injects that block only to the service.

For example, in the Extension class:

```
class MyNiceProjectExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load( array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container )
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $processedConfig = $this->processConfiguration( $configuration, $configs );
        
        // Do not add a paramater now, just continue reading the services.
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader( $container, new FileLocator( __DIR__ . '/../Resources/config' ) );
        $loader->load( 'services.yml' );
        
        // Once the services definition are read, get your service and add a method call to setConfig()
        $sillyServiceDefintion = $container->getDefinition( 'my.niceproject.sillymanager' );
        $sillyServiceDefintion->addMethodCall( 'setConfig', array( $processedConfig[ 'contact_email' ] ) );
    }
}
```

Then in your `services.yml` you define your service as usual, without any absolute change:

```
services:
    my.niceproject.sillymanager:
        class: My\NiceProjectBundle\Model\SillyManager
        arguments: []
```

And then in your `SillyManager` class, just add the method:

```
class SillyManager
{
    private $contact_email;
    
    public function setConfig( $newConfigContactEmail )
    {
        $this->contact_email = $newConfigContactEmail;
    }
}
```

Note that this also works for arrays instead of scalar values! Imagine that you configure a rabbit queue and need host, user and password:

```
my_nice_project:
    amqp:
        host: 192.168.33.55
        user: guest
        password: guest
```

Of course you need to change your Tree, but then you can do:

```
$sillyServiceDefintion->addMethodCall( 'setConfig', array( $processedConfig[ 'amqp' ] ) );
```

and then in the service do:

```
class SillyManager
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    
    public function setConfig( $config )
    {
        $this->host = $config[ 'host' ];
        $this->user = $config[ 'user' ];
        $this->password = $config[ 'password' ];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're wondering what's different between the first approach and the documentation, it's that the config values are converted into parameters in the `MyNiceProjectExtension->load()` method with this line: `$container->setParameter( 'my_nice_project.contact_email', $processedConfig[ 'contact_email' ]);`. Thanks Xavi!

Comment: Perfect answer, shame symfony doesn't let you access config the same way it does parameters.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it does expose Symfony's obtuse way of "configuring" an application. What's the point of having arbitrary environment config files when you have to write and invoke specific services to access them. Didn't somebody at Symfony sit there and realize, 'Maybe developers would actually want to provide environment specific values in their applications that they can access' Kind of the point of config files isn't it? They're following the "STKTFANREO" design pattern: "Set the knobs to F'd and rip 'em off"

Comment: It has several applications, specially in deploying parallelized automatic-testing, and specially when a team develops a bundle that is mainly model or logic that is consumed by several other teams in different applications, for example an application that is a user front-end, another one that is an admin-panel web front and another one that is a REST API. Each of those is a different application willing to configure diferetenly. That is multiplied by several environments (production, pre-production, testing, devel, etc.). This easily yields in 12 or 15 configurations in a single company.

Comment: @XaviMontero I followed your instruction SECOND APPROACH: and when  var_dump the $this->contact_email  or add an exit() in function setConfig() it doesn't exit.

It looks like setConfig doesn't get called

Comment: Some tips: 1) Did you invoke the `setConfig()` via the `addMethodCall()`? 2) `$this->contact_email` is defined by the private property. Did you set it up? 3) `$this->contact_email` does *not* have any value at the beginning of the `setConfig()` as you are, precisely, setting it from `$newConfigContactEmail` which in turn comes from `array( $processedConfig[ 'contact_email' ] )`in the `load()`. Can you `var_dump()` the `$newConfigContactEmail` in `setConfig()` and the `$processedConfig[]` in the `load()`?. Hope to help. If this gets longer let's open a chat instead of using the comments.

Comment: In fact, by yor comment "It looks like setConfig doesn't get called" maybe you should take a closer look to those two lines: `$sillyServiceDefintion = $container->getDefinition( 'my.niceproject.sillymanager' );         $sillyServiceDefintion->addMethodCall( 'setConfig', array( $processedConfig[ 'contact_email' ] ) );` and therefore trace that the `public function load( array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container )` is really being executed. Hope to help.

Comment: @XaviMontero, Thanks for the response. I have set and invoked everything. I var_dumped $sillyServiceDefintion  and inside calls: there is the array with the 0 => 'setConfig', 1 => array ('value1')
array( $processedConfig[ 'contact_email' ] has a value when var_dump and I have even used a array('string') to test it as well.

Comment: Chat opened: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127710/help-on-question-4821692 - "Avoid chatting in the comments" is a rule of the StackExchange community. Move to the chat, ping me there.

Comment: That's crazily complex for just wanting to access a config parameter.

Comment: This is the definition of "overengineered".

Answer (score 36):

I have to add to the answer of douglas, you can access the global config, but symfony translates some parameters, for example:

```
# config.yml
... 
framework:
    session:
        domain: 'localhost'
...
```

are

```
$this->container->parameters['session.storage.options']['domain'];
```

You can use var_dump to search an specified key or value.

Comment: Just a note that parameters is private in symfony 3+

Answer (score 16):

In order to be able to expose some configuration parameters for your bundle you should consult the documentation for doing so. It's fairly easy to do :)

Here's the link: [How to expose a Semantic Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)

Comment: Honestly, this question was asked over 2 years ago, back then, the above article didn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

Like it was saying previously - you can access any parameters by using injection container and use its parameter property.

["Symfony - Working with Container Service Definitions"](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html) is a good article about it.

Answer (score 3):

I learnt a easy way from code example of http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/

1) notice the ZendeskBlueFormBundle and file location

```
# myproject/app/config/config.yml

imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: @ZendeskBlueFormBundle/Resources/config/config.yml }

framework:
```

2) notice Zendesk_BlueForm.emails.contact_email and file location

```
# myproject/src/Zendesk/BlueFormBundle/Resources/config/config.yml

parameters:
    # Zendesk contact email address
    Zendesk_BlueForm.emails.contact_email: dunnleaddress@gmail.com
```

3) notice how i get it in $client and file location of controller

```
# myproject/src/Zendesk/BlueFormBundle/Controller/PageController.php

    public function blueFormAction($name, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3, Request $request)
    {
    $client = new ZendeskAPI($this->container->getParameter("Zendesk_BlueForm.emails.contact_email"));
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a controller:

```
$this->container->getParameter('configname')
```

to get the config from `config/config.yaml`:

```
parameters:
   configname: configvalue
```