# Symfony 2 configuration for Command

Tags: command-line, configuration, symfony

Does anyone know the best way I can create a configuration for a Console/Command-line Command (or indeed in any part of the application?)

What I would like to achieve is this (for example)

```
$ app/console myapp:sync --server=server_2
connecting to "server2.servers.com"...success!
sync completed.
```

Where myapp is a command line class under /src/myBundle/Command/SyncCommand.php
and in the configuration (app/config/config.yml?) this:

```
myapp:
    server_1:
        hostname: "server1.servers.com"
        port: 22
    server_2:
        hostname: "server2.servers.com"
        port: 22
```

For this example it isn't important what the sync does (the code has already been written as SyncCommand.php), I am just interested in knowing in which configuration file to use (I presume either config.yml or parameters.ini) and how to read that config out (treeBuilder? or something like $this->getParameters('myapp')? I suspect I am missing something obvious somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the command you have access to the container with getContainer() method if you extend the [ContainerAwareCommand](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/index.html?q=Symfony%5CBundle%5CFrameworkBundle%5CCommand%5CCommand) class.

You can define your configurations in the parameters section of the services file:

```
parameters:
    server_1:
        hostname: "server1.servers.com"
        port: 22
    server_2:
        hostname: "server2.servers.com"
        port: 22
```

Then you should be able to access them with the container (just like described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821692/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml)):

```
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('server_1');
```