# Symfony2: accessing variables defined in config.yml and config_*.yml

Tags: php, symfony

Let's say I have a simple traditional contact form on my site and I would like it to use the subject "Test: (subject_field value)" in dev environment and "(subject_field_value)" in prod environment when sending e-mail. Is there a way to define a variable called "subject_prefix" in config_dev.yml and config_prod.yml and then just use something like `$this->get('config')->get('subject_prefix')`? I would expect that call to return "Test: (subject_field value)" in dev environment and "(subject_field_value)" in prod environment.

Answer (score 8):

The best to do is :

In the **config.yml**

```
parameters:
    url: domain.com
```

In the **controller** :

```
$value = $this->container->getParameter('url');
```

Hope it helps.

In Symfony 2.7+:

```
$value = $this->getParameter('url');
```

Answer (score 4):

See the [*How to expose a Semantic Configuration for a Bundle*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) cookbook article.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to clutter your "parameters.yml" and do want to store it in the config.yml and config_dev.yml look at my answer here:

[How do I read configuration settings from Symfony2 config.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821692/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml)

The one that contains the two approaches:

- FIRST APPROACH: Separated config block, getting it as a parameter
- SECOND APPROACH: Separated config block, injecting the config into a service

Hope this helps!