# How to read configuration values from config.yml in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Please note: I know how to read **parameters** from parameters.yml.

I have been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821692/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544392/symfony2-accessing-variables-defined-in-config-yml-and-config-yml) and none answer my question.

I need to read configuration values from config.yml which are not **parameters**.

What I want to do exactly is to read some configurations from another vendor bundle.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your best bet is to look the dependency injection extension for your vendor.  The code will show how the config files are processed.  In most cases you will then be able to access the data you need via services.  Or, do as @devict suggests, and just read the config files directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a prettier way to do it, but you should try using the YAML component : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html

Comment: Prettier ??? this is the worst one ;) Symfony configuration file use cache to avoid parsing yaml files on each request...

Comment: True.  But there is no standard way to directly read the cached version of config.yml.  Simple reason for that:  There is no cache version of config.yml.  Each bundle process their own variables. The processed information ends up being cached so you don't have to redo the processing stuff on each request.  The only way to read the config files from different vendor bundles is to read them directly.