# get global parameters in Entity Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'd like to retrieve the Global Parameters from config.yml to entity

```
    twig:
    ..
        globals:
            image404: image-missing.png
```

and i want use this param from my static var like:

```
class Foo extends Bar {

    private static $image404 = "HERE GLOBAL PARAM";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
 var_dump($this->container->parameters);
```

and have a look at the parameter names. There are not always equal to the names in your config.yml. E.g.

```
$this->container->parameters['twig.globals']['image404'];
```

may return null. This question was already asked: **[How do I read configuration settings from Symfony2 config.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821692/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml)**

Comment: if i use xdebug inside Foo,I haven't `$this->container` but `$this` is my object bundle `{Acme\FooBundle\Entity\Foo}` ... Thanks