# GetConfig() in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, yaml

I looked after this, but I didn't found something useful.
Is there a method like Symfony1.4 getConfig() in Symfony2.7 to get a config value from a Yaml file? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of define hard-coded configuration values, create a parameter :

```
# app/config/parameters.yml or app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    your_param: value # Define the parameter
```

Use it in your configuration :

```
# app/config/config.yml
my_package:
    my_parameter: "%your_param%"
```

Retrieve it from your controller or another context which can access the service container :

```
$this->container->getParameter('yourparam');
```

See [DI and parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) and [How do I read configuration settings from Symfony2 config.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821692/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml)

Comment: Thanks @chalasr, I used a mix of this solution and a little bit of hard coding to adapt this to my needs