# Get bundle config value with interpolated parameters in Symfony3

Tags: symfony

I have a bundle with its custom `*Extension` class where I need to read configuration from another bundle (SecurityBundle in particular) where I have for example.

```
security:
    ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: '^%url_prefix%'
```

I'm wondering how can I get value for `security.firewalls.main.pattern` with interpolated `url_prefix` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving configuration values (of any bundle different than the one into what your extension is located, because you are in an extension) is not supported, and it seems that'll not be in the future.

The only ways are:

Define a parameter representing the whole option's value (as pointed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821692/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml) on a similar question):

```
# app/config/security.yml
parameters:
    firewalls.main.pattern: '^%url_prefix%'
    # ...
security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: '^%url_prefix%'
```

Parse your `config.yml` using the [Yaml component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html#reading-yaml-files):

```
$yamlPath = $this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/config/security.yml';
$config = Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($yamlPath));

// The option value
$value = $config['security']['firewalls']['main']['pattern'];
```

I think that's really a pity to don't be able to retrieve a config option from any container-aware context without doing such hacks.

Comment: I written a bundle for that. https://github.com/chalasr/RCHConfigAccessBundle , allowing to retrieve any config value using dot syntax, here it would be: `$pattern = container->get('rch_config_access.accessor')->get('security.firewalls.main.pattern');`