# How to get parameters of a service inside symfony controllers?

Tags: php, symfony

Say I have a app/config/parameters.yml which contains

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    ...
nacho_image: 
    upload: true
    progress: false 
    key: secret_id
```

Now, I would like to get `upload, progress, key` in my controller, but doing

```
$this->get('upload'); 
$this->get('nacho_image.upload'); 
$this->get('nacho.image.upload'); 
$this->getParameter('nacho.upload'); 
$this->getParameter('acho_image.upload.upload');
```

doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read configuration settings from Symfony2 config.yml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821692/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml)

Comment: @KhorneHoly This is not the same, I am not nesting the configs under `parameters`

Comment: It is, have a look at the second answer, that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly get a nested parameter. you have to get the parent key and you will get all the content as an array

```
$nachoImageConfig = $this->getParameter('nacho_image');
$nachoImageUpload = $nachoImageConfig['upload'];
```

From the doc (http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html):

> The used . notation is just a Symfony convention to make parameters easier to read. Parameters are just flat key-value elements, they can't be organized into a nested array

That is why in most config files, the entries under 'parameters:' are fully qualified like this:

```
parameters:

    ...

    nacho_image.upload: true
    nacho_image.progress: false 
    nacho_image.key: secret_id
```

Comment: I get an error `nacho_image must be defined` same as I was getting before, do you think there is a problem with nesting unrelated config under one namespace: parameters?

Comment: did you indent your file properly ? `nacho_image` must be indented with 4 spaces like `database_driver`

Comment: Yes, it is indented properly otherwise yaml would throw out an error, nacho_image is another symfony bundle so maybe it is not posible to share other bundles parameters

Comment: all your parameters need to be defined in the global file in `app/config/parameters.yml`

Comment: Yes, they are all in `/app/config/parameters.yml` I am not using anything else, it is the same file where my database credientials are stored

Comment: can you paste the content of this file in your question ?

Comment: I don't know what is happening, it is a really simple file http://pastebin.com/b0s1egxk

Comment: ok so that is what @KhorneHoly and I said : you have not indented your parameter properly you have to indent like this : http://pastebin.com/zWWaiWcB otherwise, symfony will not know it is a parameter

Comment: You don't understand I can not put nacho_image within the parameters level, because the bundle nacho_image will not find it, so it stays where it is and I just want to get the it's contens in my controller. In short your solution will work on how to get the parameter inside my controller, but it will break the bundle that depends on it

Comment: Anyway, thaks for the help I understand now it is possible but not simple

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error, because your .yml file isn't well formatted. Your `nacho_image` parameter isn't within the range of the parameters part, but on the same `level`, so you can't access it over the parameters.

Edit your parameters shown as below, then you can access your parameters.

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    ...
    nacho_image: 
        upload: true
        progress: false 
        key: secret_id
```

For everything else look @CROZET's answer.

If you need to access an value from the config, that isn't set within the `parameters` section, you could do it the way that is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821692/how-do-i-read-configuration-settings-from-symfony2-config-yml#22599416).

Comment: How do I access, if it's outside the parameter namespace or if it is on the same level? because nacho_image is another bundle and if I put it under parameters that other bundle will be broken

Comment: @mvrht Edited my answer